# Disparity Map vs Left Image(reference image)

Tags: opencv, stereoscopy

I'm really having a hard time matching every pixel of the image with its corresponding disparity value, as the disparity map is way more shifted to the right than the original image. And it looks more stretched than the original.

[image: sample.png]

As you can see, the object in the original image is way thinner than its disparity. How can I fix this?

Since I cannot figure out how to retrieve the original (x,y) of points from the original image using when using `reprojectImageTo3D`